# Trial solution for in-homogenous differential equation with complex numbers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve following:
Now I have to find trial solutions for the particular solutions, however, I struggle here:

The solutions are given in the right order
I have tried to define the homogenous solution first and get to the solution: $y_h=c_0cos(2x)+c_1sin(2x)+c_3xcos(2x)+c_4sin(2x)$. And then I tried to determine the trial solutions taking the multiplicity of solutions into account by comparing. However, I don't get the solution provided above. Especially for the third one.

Comment: This makes no sense. $$q^4+4q^2+16=(q^2+4)^2-4q^2=(q^2+2q+4)(q^2-2q+4)$$ has roots $\pm1\pm\sqrt{3}$ (all sign combinations). Contrary for the given roots in their multiplicity, the characteristic polynomial is $$(q^2+4)^2=q^4+8q^2+16,$$ giving a different middle coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y_t+4y_{t-2}+16y_{t-4}=b_t$$
You are given the solution $z=\pm 2i$ with multiplicity two.

The module of z is $|z|=\sqrt {2^2+0^2}=2$. We can deduce the angle since we have $\dfrac {z}{|z|}=i\implies \phi = \dfrac {\pi} 2$. Therefore the solution to the homogeneous difference equation is:
$$y_h=\color{red}{2^t }\left(c_1 \cos(\frac {\pi}2t)+c_2 \sin(\frac {\pi}2t)+c_3 t\cos(\frac {\pi}2t)+c_4 t\sin(\frac {\pi}2t) \right)$$
You can deduce why you have to multiply by $t^2$ in the third option and why you don't have to multiply for the first and second option. Do you get it ?

Comment: Wow, thank you. In this case now everything is quite clear! But then the solutions of my reasoning to the original problems of this thread would be wrong.

Comment: YW.  Your solution wasn't correct thats why. @randomname Your reasoning for the first problem the differential equation is correct. It's the solution in the second problem the difference equation that is wrong.

Comment: Ah okay. So it does make a difference whether it is a solution of a difference or differential equation. I will try to remember that I have to redefine the angle and radius when it comes to a difference equation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck for your exam @randomname

Answer (score 1):

$$y^{4} + 4y'' + 16y = b(x)$$
Since the complementary solution is:
$$y_h=c_0\cos(2x)+c_1\sin(2x)+c_3x\cos(2x)+c_4\sin(2x)$$
And given that: 
$$b(x)=x\sin 2x$$
We have to first choose a particular solution of the form:
$$y_p=(Ax+B)\sin 2x+ (Cx+D)\cos 2x$$
But since $\sin 2x $ is already part of the homogeneous solution we multiply the solution by x. Then we have $Bx \sin 2x $ and this is also part of the homogeneous solution so we have to multiply our guess by $x^2$. Hence we have:
$$y_p=x^2(Ax+B)\sin 2x+ x^2(Cx+D)\cos 2x$$

For your second question. The guess should be $y_p=at^2+bt+c$. No need to multpily by $t^2$ the guess. It's maybe just a mistake. Since we have:
$$(r^2+1)(r-1)^2=0$$
The differential equation is:
$$y^{(4)}-2y'''+2y''-2y'+y=0$$
The inhomogeneous equation is:
$$y^{(4)}-2y'''+2y''-2y'+y=2t^2+1$$
Here is the solution provided by Wolfram [WA solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%27-2y%27%27%27%2B2y%27%27-2y%27%2By%3D2t%5E2%2B1)

So that the particular solution is:
$$y_p=2t^2+8t+9$$
And the homogeneous solution is:
$$y_h=c_0e^x+c_1xe^x+c_3\cos(x)+c_4\sin(x)$$
It's a polynomial of degree two not four as written in your book.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. The first part is very clear to me now. And actually your answer for the second problem does match my own solution. I don't know how they get to $t^2$. And thank you for the Wolfram link. I didn't know it existed. Btw, I stumbled upon another set of question. I tried to solve them. Do you mind to take a look in the answer section?

Comment: @randomname, you're welcome. The $t^2$ is just a typo. Yes you can post them .

Comment: thank you so much :) I have just posted them. Let's find out what' wrong with my solution.